# Arduino Mega2560, Ethernet Shield & OV0706: "Camera not found"

Tags: arduino-mega, sd-card

I want to take a picture with the OV0706 and save it to an SD card. I'm using an Arduino Mega2560, Ethernet Shield (with SD slot) and [an OV0706](http://www.aliexpress.com/item/NEW-RS232-TTL-JPEG-Digital-Serial-Camera-Module-SCB-1-with-video-out-Support-VIMICRO-VC0706/1975852463.html). I tried the tutorial for this camera from Adafruit, but I'm still getting a 'No camera found?' error.

I thought it had something to do with assigning the pins, but if I connect the RX from the OV0706 with A15 on the Mega (see picture), it still gives the same error.

```cpp
// On Mega: camera TX connected to pin 69 (A15), camera RX to pin 3:
SoftwareSerial cameraconnection = SoftwareSerial(69, 3);
```

The code (important part):

```cpp
// This is a basic snapshot sketch using the VC0706 library.
// On start, the Arduino will find the camera and SD card and
// then snap a photo, saving it to the SD card.
// Public domain.

// If using an Arduino Mega (1280, 2560 or ADK) in conjunction
// with an SD card shield designed for conventional Arduinos
// (Uno, etc.), it's necessary to edit the library file:
//   libraries/SD/utility/Sd2Card.h
// Look for this line:
//   #define MEGA_SOFT_SPI 0
// change to:
//   #define MEGA_SOFT_SPI 1
// This is NOT required if using an SD card breakout interfaced
// directly to the SPI bus of the Mega (pins 50-53), or if using
// a non-Mega, Uno-style board.

#include <Adafruit_VC0706.h>
#include <SPI.h>
#include <SD.h>

// comment out this line if using Arduino V23 or earlier
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>         

// uncomment this line if using Arduino V23 or earlier
// #include <NewSoftSerial.h>       

// SD card chip select line varies among boards/shields:
// Adafruit SD shields and modules: pin 10
// Arduino Ethernet shield: pin 4
// Sparkfun SD shield: pin 8
// Arduino Mega w/hardware SPI: pin 53
// Teensy 2.0: pin 0
// Teensy++ 2.0: pin 20
#define chipSelect 4

// Pins for camera connection are configurable.
// With the Arduino Uno, etc., most pins can be used, except for
// those already in use for the SD card (10 through 13 plus
// chipSelect, if other than pin 10).
// With the Arduino Mega, the choices are a bit more involved:
// 1) You can still use SoftwareSerial and connect the camera to
//    a variety of pins...BUT the selection is limited.  The TX
//    pin from the camera (RX on the Arduino, and the first
//    argument to SoftwareSerial()) MUST be one of: 62, 63, 64,
//    65, 66, 67, 68, or 69.  If MEGA_SOFT_SPI is set (and using
//    a conventional Arduino SD shield), pins 50, 51, 52 and 53
//    are also available.  The RX pin from the camera (TX on
//    Arduino, second argument to SoftwareSerial()) can be any
//    pin, again excepting those used by the SD card.
// 2) You can use any of the additional three hardware UARTs on
//    the Mega board (labeled as RX1/TX1, RX2/TX2, RX3,TX3),
//    but must specifically use the two pins defined by that
//    UART; they are not configurable.  In this case, pass the
//    desired Serial object (rather than a SoftwareSerial
//    object) to the VC0706 constructor.

// Using SoftwareSerial (Arduino 1.0+) or NewSoftSerial (Arduino 0023 & prior):
#if ARDUINO >= 100
// On Uno: camera TX connected to pin 2, camera RX to pin 3:
//SoftwareSerial cameraconnection = SoftwareSerial(2, 3);
// On Mega: camera TX connected to pin 69 (A15), camera RX to pin 3:
SoftwareSerial cameraconnection = SoftwareSerial(69, 3);
#else
NewSoftSerial cameraconnection = NewSoftSerial(2, 3);
#endif

Adafruit_VC0706 cam = Adafruit_VC0706(&cameraconnection);

// Using hardware serial on Mega: camera TX conn. to RX1,
// camera RX to TX1, no SoftwareSerial object is required:
//Adafruit_VC0706 cam = Adafruit_VC0706(&Serial1);

void setup() {

  // When using hardware SPI, the SS pin MUST be set to an
  // output (even if not connected or used).  If left as a
  // floating input w/SPI on, this can cause lockuppage.
#if !defined(SOFTWARE_SPI)
#if defined(__AVR_ATmega1280__) || defined(__AVR_ATmega2560__)
  if(chipSelect != 53) pinMode(53, OUTPUT); // SS on Mega
#else
  if(chipSelect != 10) pinMode(10, OUTPUT); // SS on Uno, etc.
#endif
#endif

  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println("VC0706 Camera snapshot test");
  
  // see if the card is present and can be initialized:
  if (!SD.begin(chipSelect)) {
    Serial.println("Card failed, or not present");
    // don't do anything more:
    return;
  }  
  
  // Try to locate the camera
  if (cam.begin()) {
    Serial.println("Camera Found:");
  } else {
    Serial.println("No camera found?");
    return;
  }
```

Thanks in advance.

(Pictures: http://prntscr.com/apdvi9 )

Answer (score 0):

Since at least my camera needs up to 2 seconds to initialize, I think the

```
if (cam.begin()) {
Serial.println("Camera Found:");
} else {
Serial.println("No camera found?");
```

returns immediately what it thinks No camera found

Try it with

```
    unsigned long timer = millis();
    Serial.println("Camera initializing:");
    while (!cam.begin()) {
    Serial.print(".");
    if (millis()-timer>3000) {
      Serial.println("No camera found?");
      break;
      }
    }
```